# Antenna RF cable of Flat notch antenna

Tags: antenna

As in Attached pics its wide band flat notch antenna, Why it having two RF cable to connect. Is it for antenna diversity or for somewhat.

Datasheet link is below, couldn't find much info on this.

[image]

http://taoglas.com/images/product_images/original_images/FXUB71.A.07.C.001.pdf

Comment: I have Cell modem which has two UFL connector for Antenna diversity , So As i understand I cant not use this antenna. Right?

Comment: you need to select an antenna that is compatible with the specifications of your modem, consult the manual and take note of the characteristics of the antennas that it uses.  Failing to use the correct kind of antennas may damage the TX/RX components in your device.

Answer (score 0):

MIMO is discussed in the datasheet.  Diversity is a sub-set of MIMO.

MIMO stands for Multiple Input Multiple Output (signals).  And would explain the two coaxial leads.

For more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIMO